# PHP parsererror ajax get returns array of strings

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am having a problem trying to get around a "parsererror" that is returned from my ajax request, despite a response in devtools which is an array of strings. I have a click event that makes an ajax request to pull in information from a database. The result in dev tools is:

```
1["1","admin","admin@admin.com","test","2017-01-11 00:00:00"]
```

I was expecting it to be a json object { }.

The code I wrote for the click event is:

```
$('#viewProfile').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'api.php',
        data: "",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var id = data[0];
            var name = data[1];
            $('#userDetails').html("<p>ID: " + id + " Name: " + name + "</p>");
        },
        error: function(request, error) {
            $('#userDetails').html("<p>There was a problem: " + error + "</p>");
        }


    });


});
```

The php I wrote for api.php

```
    session_start();
echo $_SESSION['user_session'];

//DECLARE VARS FOR DB
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "dbregistration";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_tablename = "tbl_users";

//CONNECT TO DB
include 'dbconfig.php';
$db_con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);
$dbs = mysqli_select_db($db_con, $db_name);

//QUERY DB FOR DATA
$result = mysqli_query($db_con, "SELECT * FROM $db_tablename where user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_session']."' ");
$array = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

//RETURN RESULT
echo json_encode($array);
```

I have tried in api.php to use json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) along with changing the datatype to HTML, which obviously did not work. In short, my goal was to be able to fire the click event, send an ajax request to retrieve information from the database, based on the user id then return that to the #userDetails id on the page. I am stuck trying to get around the array of strings that seems to be the roadblock for me.

Comment: you need to remove this line `echo $_SESSION['user_session'];`

Comment: that's not an array of strings, it's a json string that is preceeded by the string `1`, thus making it an invalid json string.

Comment: Sidenote: `$dbs = mysqli_select_db($db_con, $db_name);` you don't need that. You already declared all 4 arguments in `mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name)`.

Comment: Add `mysqli_error($db_con)` to the query also, what does that throw you? as well as looking at your console and error reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
echo $_SESSION['user_session'];
```

and change this:

```
$array = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

to this:

```
$array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

EDIT: you should also be checking for success/failure of your various db-related statements:

```
$db_con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name) or die("there was a problem connecting to the db");
$dbs = mysqli_select_db($db_con, $db_name) or die("Could not select db");
```

and also

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_con, "SELECT * FROM $db_tablename where user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_session']."' ");
if (!$result) {
    die("query failed");
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason my answer was voted down? Kinda sucks to attempt helpful answer only to be penalized for it.

Comment: agreed. I'm positive the answer resolves the issue as well.

Comment: Thank you. @LarsStegelitz I agree downvotes should explain themselves for any reasonable effort at questions or answers.

Answer (score -1):

This needs to be removed `echo $_SESSION['user_session']` it is getting returned to ajax call and because it is on json the return is incorrect.